# OSX scp without -c <cipher>, default cipher

Tags: ssh, terminal, encryption, scp

I was wondering what the default cipher was for `scp`, if there's any. Do I have to explicitly specify a cipher or there's a default? I could not find this in its man, nor on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The default list of ciphers is in manual page for `ssh_config`. My version have:

> The default is:
>
> ```
> chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,
> aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,
> aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,
> aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
> ```

What cipher of them is used is negotiated during the key exchange. You can observe how does it work when you add one or more `-v` switches to your `scp` command.

> Do I have to explicitly specify a cipher or there's a default?

You don't need to specify ciphers, unless the remote end (server) is using some very old and broken ciphers, that are disabled in current client.

Comment: Hey! Thanks! My problem is that with `-v`, nothing extra happens... That's why I asked the question. Is it possible that `scp` does not use any cipher?

Comment: I even specify a cipher `scp -pv -c aes256-cbc <source> <host>`, but nothing happens... while the files got copied, of course!

Comment: No, it is not possible. `scp` always uses a cipher. Try `scp -pvvv -c aes256-cbc <source> <host>`